# jwt io - unable to replace the default value

Tags: java, selenium, jwt, access-token

I want to replace the default value present in the textbox in link: https://jwt.io/ and then enter the token i have. But currently I am unable to clear the contents by using .clear() and .sendkeys(keys.backspace()). Can you please help me here? How can we clear the default contents and replace it with the required value?

Answer (score 0):

```
        Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
        actions.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='input js-input']")));
        actions.click();
        actions.sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL,"a");
        actions.sendKeys(Keys.BACK_SPACE);
        actions.click();
        actions.sendKeys("SOME DATA");
        actions.build().perform();
```

this works for me